# subsetting rows by index - Equivalent of dt[-c(1,2,3), ] with subset

Tags: r

I have been looking for an **equivalent to the row subsetting using index of rows, but using the function subset()**.

Example:

```
vector01 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
toremove <- which(vector01 == 0)

dt <- data.frame(Kingdom = c(T,T,T,T,F), Phylum = c(T, T ,F,F,T), Class = c(T, F ,F, F, T),
   row.names=c("GenSpe1", "GenSpe2", "GenSpe3", "GenSpe4", "GenSpe5"), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt <- dt[-toremove, ]
```

In the end I want to do something like this, to only keep rows matching a condition in column "Phylum" and removing the lines I previously flagged:

subset(dt, Phylum == T & !(row,names(dt) %in% toremove) )

I have a dataset containing species names as `row.names`.
I extract indexes of rows to remove from a vector I got using apply function.

Normally, I would do a simple `dt[-rowtoremove, ]` but I can't find an equivalent with `subset()`.
The only equivalent would be to remove rows based on their names which is either impossible in my case or risky if the `row.names` haven't been reset.
Not that I don't like the old good way but I just prefer `subset()` for the clarity of the synthax which becomes easier to read when combining logical expressions.

The other solution would go for a pipe and split the steps `(logical expression1 & log exp2) -->`

---

```
dt %<>% dt[-rowstoremove, ] %>% filter with logexpr2
```

---

Still I think there should exist a way with subset that I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance,

---

EDIT:
I just tried to put the subsetting I do on my vector inside the subset. It seems to work although not very aesthetic.

Before:

```
toremove <-- which(vector01[] == 0)
dt <-- dt[-toremove, ]
```

After:

```
subset(dt, vector01[] == 0)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: if you want to keep only the `vector01==1` rows simply use: `mtcars %>% subset(subset=vector01)`, as 1 is equal to TRUE and 0 equal to FALSE.

Comment: `if(myAnswerHelps) {mark as answer} else {tell me what its missing}; print("thank you")`

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to ever use `subset`. There are even some situations where using `subset` is dangerous (see its documentation).

Comment: @AndreElrico strangely, subset doesn't want my 0,1 and asks for logicals. I check the class of the vector and it is a numerical vector so it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @Roland That's how I learned R and have been using it for years.

Comment: @PierreO consider Roland's advice. Just trying to answer your question here. Try using `as.logical(vector01)` inside `subset=` argument

Comment: You can't mix logical and index subsetting. The solution is chaining: `tabres[-noninc,][!tabres[-noninc, "Class"]]`

Comment: @Roland I am having a look at how to write this with the subsetting operator [ but I somehow don't get the same results. I wrote it as (I updated the example in the post): notaclass <- tabres[tabres$Class== F & -noninc,] How do I select the lines that are not "Class" but dropping also the lines don't want to include?

Comment: @Roland I did not know that! I manage to do the chain with the pipe too.
I am just a lot less used to the subset operator for more complex subsets. I guess I'll try to practise that.
Edit: I just tried and I get an error "Class" = undefined column selected although it is in my table. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you want to remove rows 1:10 from `mtcars` with `subset`.

```
 rowsToRemove <- 1:10
 mtcars %>% subset(subset=!(rownames(.) %in% rownames(.)[rowsToRemove]))
```

Comment: Thank you! It does the trick. I am just surprised there is not a shorter syntax for this matter like a "index %in% toremove" where index would extract the true index of the data.frame passed to subset().

Answer (score 2):

some short ways:

```
subset(dt,!seq(nrow(dt)) %in% toremove)         # shortest I could think of
subset(dt,!`[<-`(logical(nrow(dt)),toremove,T)) # more efficient
```

But I'd just use `dplyr::slice`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% slice(-toremove)
```

Comment: Good to know that function slice(). Seems useful! thanks for your answer.